# PHP require Link

Tags: php, require

When attempting to link from the root directory in my PHP file, I am unable to load the file. It works fine unless I add the file path as absolute, like so:

```
<link href="/supportfiles/subheader/css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <div id="subheadingContainer">
    <div id="allContentContainer">
        <?php 

          if (count($loggedIn["directReports"]) != 0 ) {
            require("/supportfiles/subheader/itemshtml/inbox.php");
          } else {
            require("/supportfiles/subheader/itemshtml/myrequests.php");
          }

        ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why it works fine if I ../ but not if I hard code it? This is a support heading file, so im using it across multiple levels in directories and I think it should be hard coded from the root.

Comment: alternatively, you could set up a absolute path constant and use it for requiring files and stuff

Comment: Anytime I attempt to use an absolute path from the root it breaks. If I ../ or do say require("supportfiles/header/header.php"); it works fine. But if I do require("/supportfiles/header/header.php"); which is the same path it no longer works. Maybe im not quite understanding the best way to include these files?

Comment: When you use absolute paths in PHP, `/` refers to the root of your file sistem, not the root of your web aplication, this means that if you have to put the entire path including the root to your web files. In other words you have to use the path as if you accessed from your file manager, not from the browser.

Comment: Okay so I tried doing this:

Okay so I tried doing this: 

require(dirname(__FILE__) . "/supportfiles/subheader/itemshtml/inbox.php");

Which returns /Library/WebServer/Documents/supportfiles/subheader/supportfiles/subheader/itemshtml/inbox.php

However it still stops at the require line.

Comment: Sorry I hit enter and posted the comment before I was ready lol

Comment: Ok I posted the answer. I gave 2 options just if someone else needs it. You can use the second one as is the most direct to what you have now. I stay attend to any question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use absolute paths in PHP, `/` refers to the root of your file system, not the root of your web application, this means that if you want to use absolute path you have to use the path as if you accessed from your file manager, not from the browser.
For example lets say that you are working on linux with apache and that the root directory of your apache server is `/var/www/` then you would have to put:

```
require("/var/www/supportfiles/subheader/itemshtml/inbox.php");
```

if you are unsure of your document root you can use the PHP's $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. so in your case just put $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] before any absolute path and this must work just fine. so for example:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/supportfiles/subheader/itemshtml/inbox.php';
```

Comment: Okay that makes more sense now. I was confusing it with the way HTML works. Thank you!